# Why is it true that when the frequency is increased, the spread angle of the interfering waves decreases?

Tags: waves, frequency, interference

Why is it true that when the frequency is increased, the spread angle of the interfering waves decreases? I know that higher frequency means shorter wavelengths, but why does the measure of the angles decrease?

Answer (score 1):

What do you call the spread angle? The angle under which minima and maxima occur? Than it is the shorter wavelength and  if you know the formulas depending on wavelength you see it.. or just plot two circular waves, concentric  circles with different radius differences,

Answer (score 0):

If you want a formal answer, read about Fraunhofer diffraction.

If handwavy arguments are fine, then there are a few. In one, with quantum mechanics at the corner of ones mind, you can say that the higher the frequency, the more particle-like your photon is. On the other hand, we know a real particle moves along a straight line (zero spread angle). Hence as you go to shorter wavelengths, expect that your wave will spread less and less.

Another line of logic can be as follows. Spreading angle $\theta$ is a physically dimensionless quantity. Now you know $\theta$ is a function of wavelength $\lambda$ somehow. In order to construct a dimensionless expression for $\theta (\lambda)$ you need another quantity with a dimension of length. The such quantity supplied by the problem is the distance form the source to the observation point $d$. So $\theta(\lambda) = f\left(\frac{\lambda}{d}\right)$. Since it is meaningless to imagine an infinitely narrow beam with infinitely long wavelength (this makes the whole argument circular, I know. But common sense perhaps?), $f(x)$ should be a growing function of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

A handwaving answer with some implied intuition is that *diffraction* is caused by the interaction between the boundary of the opening and the wave passing through it. Consequently, the larger the opening the smaller the *apparent* effect is on the passing wave when measured relative to the amount of the undisturbed wave. Of course, the scale here is the dominant "diameter" of the opening relative to the wavelength. This idea is associated with the names of Maggi, Sommerfeld, Rubinowicz, Kottler, etc., can be rigorously demonstrated and you can read the mathematical details in Born & Wolf: Principles of Optics, Chapter 8.9 The Boundary Diffraction Wave.